# Redirecting files from a directory to subdirectory causes infinite loop

Tags: .htaccess, loops, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdirectory

Looked on here at all the answers regarding this issue but none fixes my issue. I have a directory called `pdfs` which used to contain all my .pdf files. They are now all inside `pdfs/sales` so trying to create a redirect for all files in the `pdfs` directory to look inside the `pdfs/sales` directory instead using a .htaccess file in the root of my site. Everything I've tried so far results in an infinite loop. Here's what my .htaccess looks like so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^pdfs/(.*)$ /pdfs/sales/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The first rule redirects all www. traffic to non-www. url. The second rule is my pdfs rule. The last rule is for redirecting all requests to index.php for seo friendly urls. Is there a conflict here? Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your rule like this (my comment inline):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

# remove www from domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect /pdfs/abc.pdf to /pdfs/sales/abc.pdf
RewriteRule ^pdfs/((?!(?:sales|rent)/).*)$ /pdfs/sales/$1 [R=302,NC,L]

# for all non-files and no-directories route to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thank you SO much! Works perfectly!

Comment: One more question... I also have a directory called `pdfs/rent` but now when a user goes to http://domain.com/pdfs/rent/ it redirects to `pdfs/SALES/rent`. How do I allow for that? Thanks :)